# Adding numbers that are actually strings

Tags: c#, regex, odata

I have the below code.

```
return Ok(Get(Id).Select(a => new ODataProperty
{          
    Size = a.Type == "Asset" 
        ? string.Join(",", a.AssetInfo.Size.Select(b => int.Parse(b.Size)).Sum()) 
        : null,
}).AsQueryable());
```

This code gives me errors.

An example string is: "2Gb, 4MB, 6KB".
I want to add these properties in GB using LINQ.

Comment: Convert them to integers and add them?

Comment: Can you give an example of what may be contained in that size variable?

Comment: I tried doing this: `Size1 = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines" ? string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Select(b => int.Parse(b.Size)).Sum()) : null,`....... But it does not give any result..

Comment: Why are you using `AsQueryable`?

Comment: You should store those values (possibly as bytes) in a number type and only use "GB" etc. for display. Also, `Sum` will return an `int` in your example, so there's no need to call `string.Join` on it.

Comment: Thank you Rufus.. Will do that :)

Comment: A [mcve] would be really nice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented some logic that should get you going:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Id = 1;

        var data = Get(Id).Select(a => new ODataProperty
        {
            Size = a.Type == "Asset"
                ? GetSize(a.AssetInfo.Size)
                : null
        });

        var summedSize = data.Sum(a => a.Size);
        // with your values summedSize is summedSize kilobyte
    }

    private static int? GetSize(string assetInfoSize)
    {
        // Implement some logic that will get your sizes out of the string.
        // Use some base unit e.g. all Values must be kb
        // so you need to convert all data to kb
        // 2 Gigabyte = 2000000 kilobyte
        // 4 MB = 4000 kilobyte
        // 6 KB = 6 kilobyte

        if (assetInfoSize == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var sizePart = assetInfoSize.Substring(0, assetInfoSize.Length - 2);
        var unitPart = assetInfoSize.Substring(assetInfoSize.Length - 2);

        if (unitPart.ToLower() == "gb")
        {
            return int.Parse(sizePart) * 1000000;
        }
        if (unitPart.ToLower() == "mb")
        {
            return int.Parse(sizePart) * 1000;
        }
        if (unitPart.ToLower() == "kb")
        {
            return int.Parse(sizePart);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public static List<SomeObject> Get(int id)
    {
        // Returning some sample values
        return new List<SomeObject>
        {
            new SomeObject()
            {
                Type = "Asset",
                AssetInfo = new AssetInfo
                {
                    Size = "2Gb"
                }
            },
            new SomeObject()
            {
                Type = "Asset",
                AssetInfo = new AssetInfo
                {
                    Size = "4MB"
                }
            },
            new SomeObject()
            {
                Type = "Asset",
                AssetInfo = new AssetInfo
                {
                    Size = "6KB"
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

internal class ODataProperty
{
    public int? Size { get; set; }
}

internal class AssetInfo
{
    public string Size { get; set; }
}

internal class SomeObject
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public AssetInfo AssetInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @HJain glad to hear!